# Issue in playing Post-Roll video ads | php script

Tags: javascript, php, video, video-streaming, flowplayer

I want the Post Roll video to ONLY start playing after the previous video has played. The problem is that when the Post Roll video is set to auto play is start playing but I want it to ONLY play after the previuos video has completely ended. 
 Below is the code:

```
<script>
if((typeof jQuery == "undefined") || !window.jQuery )<br>
{<br>
   var script = document.createElement("script");<br>
   script.type = "text/javascript";<br>
   script.src = "[http://vtubemobi.com/tpl/main/styles/js/jquery.js][1]";<br>
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);<br>
}<br>
var acanceltext = "Cancel";<br>
var startNextVideo,moveToNext,nextPlayUrl;<br>
</script><br>
<script><br>
  $(document).ready(function() {<br>
    fapi = flowplayer();<br>
    fapi.one("finish", function(){<br>
    startNextVideo();<br>
    });<br>
  });<br>
     $(document).ready(function() {<br>
api = flowplayer($(".flowplayer"));<br>
api.one("playing", function(){<br>
$('div.screenAd').addClass('hide');<br>
$('.plAd').addClass('hide');<br>
});<br>
api.one('ready', function(e, api, video) {<br>
api.stop(); <br>
$('.pre-roll-ad').removeClass('hide');<br>
$('.bigadclose').click(function(){ <br>
$('.pre-roll-ad').addClass('hide').remove('.pre-roll-ad'); <br>
api.play();<br>
});<br>
});<br>
api.bind('finish', function (e, api, video) {<br>
$('.post-roll-ad').removeClass('hide');<br>
$('.plAd').addClass('hide');<br>
$('.bAd').addClass('hide');<br>
$('.bigadclose').click(function(){<br>
$('div.screenAd').addClass('hide');<br>
api.play();<br>
});<br>
});<br>
```

Comment: I don't use Flow Player but in general you set one video only (eg: pre-roll), then listen for a video ending `event` where you then choose next video file to play (eg: main video). Isn't that what should be in `function startNextVideo();`?

Comment: So, you're saying that startNextVideo();? should be in the function of the Post Roll code?